# Why did I get an email saying I've asked a question on GameDevelopment.SE?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

I  just got an e-mail 3 hours ago from `do-not-reply@stackexchange.com`:

> Recently, you asked a question on Game Development Stack Exchange, but you haven't verified your email address yet.
>
> Click on the following link to verify your email and set a password so that you can log in.

I'm pretty  sure I have never asked a question here, or even known about this specific SE site's existence. Is this a bug, a january fools prank by SE, a phishing trick (can't be, do-not-reply at stackexchange is SE's official email), or has someone been using my acckount?

I've gotten the same e-mail about Sharepoint.SE, Unix.SE, Skeptics.SE, Japaneese.SE, HomeImprovement.SE, SciFi.SE, Personal Finance Money.SE  Database Admins.SE and TeX.SE. I have previously posted on TeX.SE, but not anytime recently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An account other than yours (but sharing your email address) was recently used to ask a question on the Game Development site that was considered inappropriate and deleted.

Comment: So, does that mean that someone is misusing my e-mail address? Is there any way I can stop such a thing?

Comment: Yes, it looks like somebody is using your email to register for accounts and making posts attempting to impersonate you on other SE sites. My advice, when you get an email like you described, would be to post on the meta for the site as you did in this instance (or ask for a moderator in the site's chat room). They will be able to take care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks! So should I re-post this on meta.SharePoint, meta.Unix, etc.?

Comment: I guess. You could also perhaps try to post it on meta.stackoverflow, which may get you the attention of a staff member who could address the issue more widely.

Comment: @ JoshPetrie: Thanks again!